# Connecting Apache Shiro and Cassandra Database

Tags: spring, cassandra, marionette, shiro

How to implement a connection between Apache Shiro and Cassandra Database in a web project so that shiro session management takes username and password from Cassandra database?

I have a web project(Marionette) in which there is a Login form. I want shiro to perform authentication based on usernames and passwords read from Cassandra database and not the shiro.ini file.

I am unable to establish a connection between the two.

I followed the following link but it is using shiro ini file to validate users instead of cassandra database.

https://github.com/lhazlewood/shiro-cassandra-sample

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted uses Cassandra to store the current session (in a cluster)

You would need to create your own Realm if you want to store User/password info.

See: http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/How-to-add-a-role-to-the-subject-td5562700.html
(or any of the existing Realms in Shiro to use as an example)